# result doesn't show after counting all the occurrences in an String Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i have a Text String and I use split to make it an array and I want to count ALL the occurrences of each words but i cant see any error but it doesnt show anything in my HTML this is what I want to achieve

```
[{"name":"you","data":[2]},
{"name":"it","data":[2]},
{"name":"that","data":[2]},
{"name":"to","data":[3]},
{"name":"strength","data":[2]}]
```

and here is my code in javascript

```
var counts = [];
var result = {};

var stemmed = "Example Do you really think it is weakness that yields to temptation I tell you that there are terrible temptations which it requires strength strength and courage to yield to Oscar Wilde"; 
var splitStemmed = stemmed.split(" ");

for(var i = 0; i < splitStemmed.length; i++) 
{
    for(var j = 0; j < splitStemmed.length; j++) 
    {
        if(splitStemmed[i])
        {
            if(result[splitStemmed[j]])
                result[splitStemmed[j]].data[0]++;
            else
            {
                result[splitStemmed[j]] = {name:splitStemmed[j], data:[1]};
                counts.push(result[splitStemmed[j]]);
            }
        }
    }
}

$("#show").html(counts);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this fiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/657xpksz/2/

I would say using forEach would be easier, since it doesn't involve all those different arguments like standard for loops.

Also probably no need for an array as the data value. Here's an example structure the fiddle above outputs

```
{
    "example": 1,
    "do": 1,
    "you": 2,
    "really": 1,
    "think": 1,
    "it": 2,
    "is": 1,
    "weakness": 1,
    "that": 2,
    "yields": 1,
    "to": 3,
    "temptation": 1,
    "i": 1,
    "tell": 1,
    "there": 1,
    "are": 1,
    "terrible": 1,
    "temptations": 1,
    "which": 1,
    "requires": 1,
    "strength": 2,
    "and": 1,
    "courage": 1,
    "yield": 1,
    "oscar": 1,
    "wilde": 1
}
```

This data structure is just as easy to iterate over as the one you posted, but if you need that one, the solution above can be tweaked as needed.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative approach:

```
var stemmed = "Example Do you really think it is weakness that yields to temptation I tell you that there are terrible temptations which it requires strength strength and courage to yield to Oscar Wilde"; 
var splitStemmed = stemmed.split(" ");
var hash = {};

for (var i in splitStemmed)
{
    var key = splitStemmed[i];

    if (!hash[key]) hash[key] = 0;

    hash[key]++;
}

for (var word in hash)
{
    console.log('word: ' + word + ' count: ' + hash[word]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please.

```
var counts = [];
var result = {};

    var stemmed = "Example Do you really think it is weakness that yields to temptation I tell you that there are terrible temptations which it requires strength strength and courage to yield to Oscar Wilde"; 

    var splitStemmed = stemmed.split(" ");
    var resuenter code herelt={};
    for(var i=0; i< splitStemmed.length; i++)
    {
         if(result[splitStemmed[i]]==undefined){
           result[splitStemmed[i]]=1;
         }else{
           result[splitStemmed[i]]=result[splitStemmed[i]]+1;
         }
    }
    $("#show").html(JSON.stringify(result))
```